# Is it possible to return all values returned from an API response and pass them into the pipeline to use later?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I have written the following function. It returns data from an API. It returns every value from the API call. What I would like to do is take out `print(lichess_response)` and either yield or return the reponse so I can call any value when I call the function. That way I don't have to write a function for each value.

My code:

```
#import modules
import requests
import json
import re

#retrieve lichess games for a specific user
def get_lichess_games(username):

    api_session = requests.Session()
    api_headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer CZfaketokenBWo',
        'Accept'        : 'application/x-ndjson',
    }

    with api_session.get(f'https://lichess.org/api/games/user/{username}', headers=api_headers, stream=True) as response:
        for line in response.iter_lines():
            if not line:
                continue
            lichess_response = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
            print(lichess_response)

get_lichess_games(username='overflowisaswamp')
```

An example of a single line returned from the API:

```
{'id': 'BMwE', 'rated': True, 'variant': 'standard', 'speed': 'rapid', 'perf': 'rapid', 'createdAt': 1620328262568, 'lastMoveAt': 1620328667690, 'status': 'resign', 'players': {'white': {'user': {'name': 'overflowisaswap', 'id': 'putineatspancakes5'}, 'rating': 1034, 'ratingDiff': 17}, 'black': {'user': {'name': 'uncrayon', 'id': 'uncrayon'}, 'rating': 1068, 'ratingDiff': -6}}, 'winner': 'white', 'moves': 'e4 e5 Nf3 Nc6 d4 exd4 Nxd4 Nxd4 Qxd4 Nf6 c3 Be7 Qe5 O-O b4 Nxe4 Qxe4 Re8 Be2 d5 Qe5 Bd6 Qxd5 Qe7 Qd3 g6 a3 Bf5 Qf3 Be4 Qe3 f5 O-O f4 Bc4+ Kh8 Qd4+ Be5 Qxe4 Bxc3 Nxc3 Qxe4 Nxe4 Rxe4 Bd5 Rd4 Bxb7 Rad8 Bb2', 'clock': {'initial': 600, 'increment': 0, 'totalTime': 600}}
```

I would like to yield or return rather than print, but I don't know how I would do that - something kind of like the following rough concept;

```
#import modules
import requests
import json
import re

#retrieve lichess games for a specific user
def get_lichess_games(username):

    api_session = requests.Session()
    api_headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer CZfaketokenBWo',
        'Accept'        : 'application/x-ndjson',
    }

    with api_session.get(f'https://lichess.org/api/games/user/{username}', headers=api_headers, stream=True) as response:
        for line in response.iter_lines():
            if not line:
                continue
            lichess_response = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
            #return / yield whatever I need to do to get lichess_response into the pipleline

#when I just want the id
response= get_lichess_games(username='overflowisaswamp')
print(response['id'])

#when I just want the winner
response = get_lichess_games(username='overflowisaswamp')
print(response['winner'])

#when I just want the moves
response = get_lichess_games(username='overflowisaswamp')
print(response['moves'])
```

The overall goal is to be able to reuse my function, and get any value or values I want in specific situations. Rather than write a function for moves, a function for winner, a function for id, a function for status, etc. Thanks.

Comment: `yield` seems like the right answer, but remember that will return an iterator.  You can't just `print(respose['id')]`; you'll need to `print(r['id'] for r in response)`  If you're going to extract several parts, perhaps you should collect a list instead of refetching the data each time.

Comment: Oh thanks!!!! This is super helpful. Can you elaborate on what you mean by collect a list or point me somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Your previous [question was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961261/is-it-possible-to-return-yield-all-values-from-a-rest-api-call-into-a-function?noredirect=1). Making a new account and posting the same question is unlikely to result in a different outcome. This will be much easier to answer if you can simply define what you want `response` to be.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. I want response to be the results of the api call

Comment: Are you just asking if you can add the responses to a list instead of writing them to standard output, then return that list at the end?

Comment: Your api seems to be returning more than one line, hence the question. Yet you want to use `response['winner']` -- that suggests `response` is a dictionary, which is *not* results of the api call. You need to somehow *process* those lines into a dictionary. Or maybe you want to print the `winner` from each line, but you haven't made that clear in three versions of this question.

Comment: @chepner I assume so.

Comment: @Mark The api returns thousands of lines. I don't necessarily want to do response['winner']. Thats more of an example. I want to pull back a response from the api in my function, have that function yield / return / hold every value and line of that response. Then when i call the function, I can say give me all lines but only give me he winner value. Then cal lthe function later and say give me all lines but only the id value.

Comment: Okay, so iterators can only iterate the lines once. So you need to make a choice: do you want to call the api each time you iterate over the lines (slower, but uses less memory), or do you want to store the lines in memory as a list and then process that list (faster but takes memory)?

Comment: I'd want to do both at some point, but for now, let's say in memory as a list.

Comment: You can then use `yield lichess_response` inside your loop. Then get the iterator, and make a list : `list_of_responses = list(get_lichess_games(username))`. Each item in `list_of_responses` will be a dictionary made from the corresponding line of the response.

Comment: @chepner 's answer below is a good one.  He shows one function to gather everything and return a list (which you could reuse), and one function that does a yield (which uses less memory, but has to be re-run to start the list over).

Comment: @Mark, thanks! I was able to loop through my list and get a single value and multiple values like id and moves for everything! Thanks for breaking it down. I have some reading to do now. Appreciate you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to collect what you are currently writing to standard output in a single list, that's simply

```
def get_lichess_games(username):

    api_session = requests.Session()
    api_headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer CZfaketokenBWo',
        'Accept'        : 'application/x-ndjson',
    }
    results = []
    with api_session.get(f'https://lichess.org/api/games/user/{username}', headers=api_headers, stream=True) as response:
        for line in response.iter_lines():
            if not line:
                continue
            lichess_response = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
            results.append(lichess_response)

    return results
```

If you would prefer a generator that yields values as the arrive, rather than waiting for *all* of them to arrive, use

```
def get_lichess_games(username):

    api_session = requests.Session()
    api_headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer CZfaketokenBWo',
        'Accept'        : 'application/x-ndjson',
    }
    with api_session.get(f'https://lichess.org/api/games/user/{username}', headers=api_headers, stream=True) as response:
        for line in response.iter_lines():
            if not line:
                continue
            lichess_response = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
            yield lichess_response
```

Comment: I had something super close to the first one. I was missing results.append(lichess_response). I was just doing return and it was killing the loop. What are the benefits of results.append over yield? Thanks! This helps a lot!

Comment: Say you do something like `for x in get_lichess_games(...): ...` If you append to a list, you have to wait for *all* the results to arrive before the function returns and you can finally begin to iterate over the results. With `yield`, you are basically hopping back and forth between the calling code and the function; the function suspends itself after each yield, so that you don't get the next line from `response` until your outer loop tries to get another result from your generator.

Comment: So yield is ultimately going to be better? The just do basically
list_of_responses = list(get_lichess_games(username='user'))
for index in list_of_responses:
    print(index['id']) Or if i will be doing work with the data, would it be better to use the first so I have my list available all at once?

Comment: `yield` is more *flexible*; it's not necessarily better. If you really do just want the list of results, it is slightly faster to build the list in the function and return it at once. Using `yield` allows you to interleave returning and using lines from the API response. (That is, it improves *responsiveness* in exchange for delaying the availability of the last item. It also saves memory if you don't need all the responses in memory at once. You can discard each item after processing it if desired.)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.